# Slice string from end in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, split, substring, slice

How can I split a string into multiple substrings of equal length but from back?

For example if string is: `"ABCDEFGH"`, then I want an array of each string of length 3 as:

```
["FGH", "CDE", "AB"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that this does what you're asking:

```
> "ABCDEFGH".reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/).each { |x| x.reverse! }
=> ["FGH", "CDE", "AB"]
```

Here's a quick explanation:

`.reverse` reverses the string so that it is `"HGFEDCBA"` instead of `"ABCDEFGH"`.

`.scan(/.{1,3}/)` converts the string into an array with each element of the array containing 3 characters (if the string isn't divisible by 3 then the last element of the array may have 1 or 2 characters).

`.each { |x| x.reverse! }` reverses the characters in each element of the array.

You could define a function like this:

```
def slice_string_from_end(s)
  s.reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/).each { |x| x.reverse! }
end
```

Then you can use:

```
slice_string_from_end("ABCDEFGH")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using `each_slice`, but you'll need to reverse the string first, and then *re-reverse* each individual slice:

```
x = "ABCDEFGH"
x.chars.reverse.each_slice(3).map(&:reverse).map(&:join)
=> ["FGH", "CDE", "AB"]
```

- split the string into a character array (`x.chars`)
- reverse the array (`.reverse`)
- slice the array into sub-arrays of 3 characters (`.each_slice(3)`)
- reverse each sub-array (`.map(&:reverse)`)
- join each sub-array back into a string (`.map(&:join)`)

Answer (score 2):

```
"ABCDEFGH".scan(/.+?(?=(?:.{3})*\z)/) # => ["AB", "CDE", "FGH"]
"ABCDEFGH".scan(/.+?(?=(?:.{3})*\z)/).reverse # => ["FGH", "CDE", "AB"]
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this for production code, it's an intense regular expression, but it does work well.

Answer (score 0):

[`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split) and [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) also work, but like @meagar points out, you need to reverse and then re-reverse the string:

```
"ABCDEFGH".reverse.split(/(...)/).reject(&:empty?).map(&:reverse)
# => ["FGH", "CDE", "AB"]
```

the scan one doesn't need to look for empty strings:

```
"ABCDEFGH".reverse.scan(/...?/).map(&:reverse)
# => ["FGH", "CDE", "AB"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop with some slice arithmetic:

```
s="ABCDEFGH"
li=[]
step=3
while s.length>0
    ss=s[-(step<s.length ? step : s.length)..-1]
    li << ss
    s.chomp!(ss)
end
```

Same method works with a dynamic regex:

```
s="ABCDEFGH"
li=[]
step=3
reg=".{1,#{step}}$"
while s.length>0
    ss=s[/#{reg}/]
    li << ss
    s.delete_suffix!(ss)
end
```

Either case:

```
> li
=> ["FGH", "CDE", "AB"]
```